# assertEquals(tree.contains(obj),hash.contains(obj)) returns false after overriding hashCode()

Tags: java, overriding, hashcode

One of my labs for school has me overriding both the equals and the hashCode methods. I have been able to do the equals method just fine but I'm running into some issues with the hashCode method.

My equals code looks like this, I think I did it correctly but I'm not 100% sure

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object other){
        if(this == other){
            return true;
        }
        if(other == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(!(other instanceof Polynomial)){
            return false;
        }
        Polynomial other2 = (Polynomial) other;
        if(this.getDegree() != other2.getDegree()){
            return false;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<this.getDegree();i++){
            if(this.getCoefficient(i)!=other2.getCoefficient(i)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The following is my hashCode method, I got to here by using the auto generation that eclipse offers for hashCode

```
@Override public int hashCode() {
        final int p = 31; //prime
        int res = 1;
        res = p * res + ((coefficients == null) ? 0 : coefficients.hashCode());
        res = p * res + this.getDegree();
        return res;
    }
```

I think this should be fine however I am running into an issue with the auto tester provided to us to check our labs. The issue arises with the following piece of code. BlueJ flags the assertEquals to be wrong, stating that true is expected but result was false. to be specific it's       assertEquals(tree.contains(p1), hash.contains(p1)) that is being caught by BlueJ.

```
@Test public void massTest() {
        Random rng = new Random(SEED);
        TreeSet<Polynomial> tree = new TreeSet<Polynomial>();
        HashSet<Polynomial> hash = new HashSet<Polynomial>();
        CRC32 check = new CRC32();
        for(int i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++) {
            Polynomial p1 = createRandom(rng.nextInt(10), rng);
            Polynomial p2 = createRandom(rng.nextInt(10), rng);
            assertEquals(tree.contains(p1), hash.contains(p1));
            tree.add(p1);
            hash.add(p1);
            assertEquals(0, p1.compareTo(p1));
            assertEquals(0, p2.compareTo(p2));
            assertEquals(p1.compareTo(p2), -p2.compareTo(p1));
            check.update(p1.compareTo(p2));
        }
        assertEquals(tree.size(), hash.size());
        for(Polynomial p: tree) {
            assertTrue(hash.contains(p));
        }
        for(Polynomial p: hash) {
            assertTrue(tree.contains(p));
        }        
        assertEquals(28339163L, check.getValue());
    }
}
```

My issues right now is that I can't figure out what it is exactly I'm doing wrong and to be honest I'm also not sure what it is that the assertEquals is even checking for. If someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

The exact error given to me is

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected: true but was:false
>
> at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
>
> at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
>
> at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
>
> at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
>
> at PolynomialTestThree.massTest(PolynomialTestThree.java:59)

Comment: What is the problem? In the second blob of code, if that is all you're doing, then `tree.contains(p1)` and `hash.contains(p1)` both return `false`. You've not added anything to the tree or the hash collections.

Comment: Sorry I'll update the post to contain more of the code

Comment: Please could you also include (a) your implementation of equals() and (b) what does "`getDegree()`" return. You can't do one without the other - `hashCode` and `equals` both need implementing.

Comment: " BlueJ flags the assertEquals to be wrong, stating that true is expected but result was false." There are six `assertEquals` calls. Which one?

Comment: Updated the original post with the specific line, it's assertEquals(tree.contains(p1), hash.contains(p1));

Comment: Thx. `assertEquals(tree.contains(p1), hash.contains(p1))` - p1 was just created two lines above. It has not been added to the `tree` or `hash` collections. `tree.contains(p1)` and `hash.contains(p1)` both **must** return false. false == false. AssertEquals(false, false). That should be ok. Are you 100% sure that's where it's got issues? Can you capture the value of `i` when the assertion fails? Better yet can you just dump in the `Polynominal` class in its entirety so we have the whole playing field.

Comment: BlueJ points at line 59 on PolynomialTestThree.java which is                 assertEquals(tree.contains(p1), hash.contains(p1)) which is why I originally said that was the line causing me problems. Also I noticed that it seems to be failing at i=54 everytime

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191190/discussion-between-not-a-jd-and-afc).